# Silverstripe 4 error log

Tags: silverstripe-4

How can I log errors to file log in SilverStripe 4?
I mean all errors causing 'Internal server error' info from SS

In SilverStripe it was :

```
SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogFileWriter('/var/log/silverstripe/errors.log'), SS_Log::ERR);
```

Documentation says that I need to do something like:

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  Psr\Log\LoggerInterface: 
    calls:
      LogFileHandler: [ pushHandler, [ %$LogFileHandler ] ]
  LogFileHandler:
    class: Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler
    constructor:
      - "../silverstripe.log"
      - "info"
```

I try this but cannot get this to work :(

Answer (score 6):

Try to add to your .env file [(https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/environment_management/)](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/environment_management/) such string:

```
SS_ERROR_LOG = "silverstripe.log"
```

Comment: Best solution. Thanks/

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom log try:

`use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;`

Then later:

`$logger = new Logger("my_name");
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('./silverstripe-custom.log', Logger::INFO));
$logger->info('hi there');`

You should find `silverstripe-custom.log` in the project root.