# SilverStripe - The website server has not been able to respond to your request

Tags: php, mysql, environment-variables, silverstripe

I'm trying to create my first SilverStripe website following this [tutorial](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/up-and-running-setting-up-a-local-silverstripe-dev-environment-1).

So far I have created my website and configured my .env page.

```
# DB credentials
SS_DATABASE_CLASS="MySQLDatabase"
SS_DATABASE_SERVER="localhost"
SS_DATABASE_USERNAME="root"
SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=""
SS_DATABASE_NAME="SS_examples"
SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"
```

I'm not sure entirely how the database is created when creating a site. I checked my databases and I do not have one for it. I can make one manually but I wasn't sure if I should and list it under `SS_DATABASE_NAME`, or if it will auto-create the db.

I'm assuming this is why when I visit my local site `localhost/SSexample/public` I get an error saying `"The website server has not been able to respond to your request"`.

Am I missing a step in setting up the site or should I manually create a db named `SS_examples`?

on a side note my apache server is set up with xampp and my SilverStripe project is in `C:/xamp/htdocs`.

Steps I took to create site:

1. Built site in C:\xampp\htdocs by running: `composer create-project silverstripe/installer SSexample`
2. Visited my project by going to `localhost/SSexample/public`
3. created `.env` file as listed above

**ERROR LOGS**

```
[2019-12-31 22:29:22] error-log.ERROR: Uncaught Exception SilverStripe\ORM\Connect\DatabaseException: "Couldn't run query:  SELECT DISTINCT "SiteConfig"."ClassName", "SiteConfig"."LastEdited", "SiteConfig"."Created", "SiteConfig"."Title", "SiteConfig"."Tagline", "SiteConfig"."CanViewType", "SiteConfig"."CanEditType", "SiteConfig"."CanCreateTopLevelType", "SiteConfig"."ID",             CASE WHEN "SiteConfig"."ClassName" IS NOT NULL THEN "SiteConfig"."ClassName"            ELSE 'SilverStripe\\SiteConfig\\SiteConfig' END AS "RecordClassName"  FROM "SiteConfig"  LIMIT 1  Table 'ss_lessons.siteconfig' doesn't exist" at C:\xampp\htdocs\SSlessons\vendor\silverstripe\framework\src\ORM\Connect\DBConnector.php line 64 {"exception":"[object] (SilverStripe\\ORM\\Connect\\DatabaseException(code: 0): Couldn't run query:\n\nSELECT DISTINCT \"SiteConfig\".\"ClassName\", \"SiteConfig\".\"LastEdited\", \"SiteConfig\".\"Created\", \"SiteConfig\".\"Title\", \"SiteConfig\".\"Tagline\", \"SiteConfig\".\"CanViewType\", \"SiteConfig\".\"CanEditType\", \"SiteConfig\".\"CanCreateTopLevelType\", \"SiteConfig\".\"ID\", \n\t\t\tCASE WHEN \"SiteConfig\".\"ClassName\" IS NOT NULL THEN \"SiteConfig\".\"ClassName\"\n\t\t\tELSE 'SilverStripe\\\\SiteConfig\\\\SiteConfig' END AS \"RecordClassName\"\n\r\nFROM \"SiteConfig\"\n\r\nLIMIT 1\n\nTable 'ss_lessons.siteconfig' doesn't exist at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SSlessons\\vendor\\silverstripe\\framework\\src\\ORM\\Connect\\DBConnector.php:64)"} []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the installer at `localhost/SSexample/public` should allow you to configure your database connection settings (and create the database for you).

Getting *The website server has not been able to respond to your request* error means that you have a problem with webserver - is it running?

EDIT: *The website server has not been able to respond to your request* is actually Silverstripe's generic error 500 message.

EDIT2: one has to enable dev environment - by adding `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"` to `.env` file and then access `localhost/SSexample/public/dev/build` to get database created and populated.

Comment: before I created the `.env` file from the `.env.example` I was getting an error saying `SilverStripe Framework requires database configuration defined via .env` So I assume the server is atleast able to reach the project.

Comment: As per [this forum post](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/installing-silverstripe/show/6382) try adding `?isDev=1` to the URL, it may show further error messages.

Comment: Can you actually connect to your database server on `locahost` with user `root` without password (in Adminer/phpMyAdmin/mysql console)?

Comment: yes I can. its the default setting from setting up xampp and it still works (just tried)\

Comment: Check if you can find Silverstripe's error log (or enable it - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279695/4930070) or Apache/PHP error log - these may yield additional error information.

Comment: I will try that. I also edited my question with the steps I took to build the project above.

Comment: I posted my error log above. it looks like it can't run the query which makes sense because it doesnt have a database created. should it create the db on install?

Comment: Ok, I fired up my own Silverstripe installation, got into same problems. For installation to work, you need to put `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"` to your `.env` file. Database then gets created automatically.

Comment: Do I need to run a command to get it to reinstall and create the db?

Comment: I ran `composer create-project...`, copied `.env.example` to `.env`, filled in DB connection info (user, password, database name) and added a line `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"`. Then accessed `http://localhost/SSexample/public` and got information about tables being created and populated...

Comment: ok so after the project was created you added the .env and re-visited the page and it auto did it? I added the line (edited into the question) and it still is giving me the same error.

Comment: Actually the URL I was redirected to, which created the database, was `http://localhost/SSexample/public/dev/build`

Comment: Ahh great. I visited that url and it created the table. I am now at a home page and there isn't any styling just plain text (with a tags and h tags) is that what it should look like from this point? I understand its out of the question scope I just wanted to know if yI have a different error I need to fix. Also thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This is what the app looks like (`localhost/SSexample/public`) after install - [https://imgur.com/a/QIeYdgH](https://imgur.com/a/QIeYdgH)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into finding out why the styling isn't working

Comment: NOTE: my problem lied in the fact that I created my project out of the htdocs folder and moved it there. when I recreated the project in that directory it worked fine. this has to do with the way the styles in `public/_resources/themes/simple` are created, they reference other style files which the path was not changed to when I moved the project.